# showing surjectiveness of map defined by a conjugacy

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $H$ is a subgroup of $ G$, and $g \in G$

I want to show a homomorphism $\phi: H \rightarrow g H g^{-1}$ is a surjective.

I.e, for all $y \in gHg^{-1}$, there exist $x \in H$ such that $y=\phi(x)$

The textbook says it is clear, but i am confused

In general homomorphism $\phi: H \rightarrow G$ is not surjective

but i am confused with $\phi: H \rightarrow g H g^{-1}$ is surjective

why $gHg^{-1}$ is so special?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at all the pieces we have! First, we fix some element $g\in G$. Then, we map $a\in H$ to $gag^{-1}\in gHg^{-1}$. To prove surjectivity, we need to show that there is some element $b\in gHg^{-1}$ and some element $a\in H$ such that

$$\phi(a) = b\text{, or that }gag^{-1} = b.$$

However, by definition of $gHg^{-1}$, every element of $gHg^{-1}$ can be written as $gag^{-1}$ for $a\in H$. Therefore, given $b=gag^{-1}$, we automatically know that $\phi(a) = b$ by the definition of our map $\phi$. Hence, the function is surjective.

Answer (score 1):

The inverse of $\phi : H \to g^{-1}Hg, \,\, h \mapsto g^{-1}hg$ is given by $\phi^{-1}: g^{-1}Hg \to H, \,\, y \mapsto gyg^{-1}$. Then \begin{eqnarray}
\phi \circ \phi^{-1} (y) = \phi (gyg^{-1}) = g^{-1}gyg^{-1}g = y\end{eqnarray} and
\begin{eqnarray}
\phi^{-1}\circ \phi (h) = \phi^{-1} (g^{-1}hg) = gg^{-1}hgg^{-1} = h \end{eqnarray}
Hence $\phi$ is bijective and therefore surjective.